# How do I get new localisation strings after changes in storyboard file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using localisation in my project and also having localisation files for storyboard. But when I am doing some changes in storyboard the new controls strings are not reflecting in the .strings files. I need to manually copy paste the controls code and set localisation string for each. So is there any other way to update localisation strings file for storyboard. By adding script in build phase or anything like that...

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any translations you already had in your strings file (so save them somewhere before doing this), but it might be easier to just paste translations back in, then to add storyboard objects by id.

1. Select your storyboard file.
2. In the File inspector on right, uncheck strings file you want to regenerate.

[image]

3. Check it again and it will be regenerated with new UI elements.

Comment: But with this I need to copy paste the older strings and also need to add strings for new controls which is time consuming. Is there any other way by which I get new controls strings without losing the previous ones